# A property of vec() operator and Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, kronecker-product

I know the following relationship holds between the Kronecker product  and the vectorization operator ($vec(.)$):

$vec(ABC) = (C^T \otimes A)vec(B)$

A proof for this can be found here: [https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~cnaber/Kronecker.pdf](https://www.ime.unicamp.br/%7Ecnaber/Kronecker.pdf)

I think the following equality should also be correct:

$vec(ABC) = (A^T \otimes C)vec(B)$

I tried to prove it using the same reasoning, but I couldn't. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I do not have that feeling. Write it out in $2\times 2$ and convince yourself that the expressions don't look symmetric in $A$ and $C\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for the comment. I will do that.

Comment: If the second equality held, then letting $B$ range over the standard basis would show that $C^T \otimes A = A^T \otimes C$, which is almost always false.